# NULL with SQL ABSOLUTE Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ABS(ISNULL(Convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(day, Emp.Date1 , Emp.Date)),''))
```

The above SQL code throws an error. I want to check for null values, but if it is not not null then it should be a positive value.

Comment: Your syntax is pretty clearly SQL Server so I'm removing the extraneous database tags.

Comment: Please look through the [help page on MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question could be improved by including your exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass a string to `ABS()` -- it is a numeric function.  If you want `0` to show for `NULL`:

```
ABS(COALESCE(DATEDIFF(day, Emp.Date1 , Emp.Date), 0))
```

Notes:

- Removed the conversion to a string.
- Changed `''` to `0`.  You can choose whatever value you like.
- I prefer `COALESCE()` to `ISNULL()` because the former is ANSI standard.  There are sometimes good reasons to use `ISNULL()` in SQL Server.

Note:  Never use `varchar()` without a length in SQL Server.  The default varies by context, and not being explicit can lead to very hard to find errors.  But also, don't convert to a string for functions that want a number.

EDIT:

For the empty string, put the `coalesce()` on the outside:

```
COALESCE(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, Emp.Date1, Emp.Date)), '')
```

I hadn't thought that that was your original intention . . . should have been obvious.

Comment: thanks gordon, bulls eye, new to sql, any help on getting it back to emty string

Comment: when it happens to be zero, cant print zero.